# Assuming limits in a linear derivative equation

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

[image]

Hi, I don't understand the reasoning behind the limits of $0 \leq P(0) \leq M$, and for the $k>0,$ I only managed to figure out that $K$ can't be equaled to $0$. But maybe it's because I did it in a different method from the book? I used the same $I(t)$ so got up to:

$e^{kt}p = KMe^{Kt}$

$e^{kt}p = \int Ae^{Kt}$, where $A = KM$

$e^{kt}p =  \frac AK e^{Kt}$, doing a u sub where $u=Kt$

From there, if you sub in $KM$ into $A, K$ can't be $0.$ But how did they assume the rest? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

$M$ represents the maximum learning level therefore in order to have $0\le P(0)\le M$ from the initial condition we obtain the given inequality.

The condition for $k>0$ is aimed at obtaining a growing learning when $P(t)<M$.

Comment: OHH, so is this a logistic equation then?

Comment: So the conditions are from the original equation then? since $p(t) = M+ \frac C{e^{kt}}$

Comment: It is a “reasonable model” for which we assume reasonable parameters. It seems different from logistic equation but the idea behind is similar.

Comment: But how do you get -M<=C<=0 then?

Comment: From the equation by initial condition we obtain $P(0)=M+C$ and since $0\le P(0)\le M$ we obtain $0\le M+C\le M$ that is $-M\le C\le 0$.